# After clearing Static Content, CPU Usage hits 100% for a while. How do I lessen that?

Tags: magento2, php, performance, magento2.2

After clearing Static Content, CPU Usage hits 100% for a while. How do I lessen that?

Basically, I clear Static Content so I can see my LESS changes, but every time I do, my CPU is just going crazy. I'm using xampp for windows, with Magento 2 installed to it, if that helps.

Comment: problem in your laptop, not software

Answer (score 0):

1) Magento 2 doesn't support Windows OS properly. In this case, should use Vagrant or Docker with Linux environment.

2) Our laptop should have a strong hardware: SSD, 8-16GB RAM, i5-i7 CPU.

3) Compile LESS using Grunt: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html